# Adding numbers with bases

Tags: python, binary, decimal

Hi I am having trouble with a few questions and was wondering if someone could help me.

I am suppose to add the numbers in various bases and I dont know how to do that.

Below are the questions I am having trouble with. Can someone please help.

```
Add the numbers in bases indicated (I cant figure out how to do this, can someone help!!!)

A). 4 3 7 1 base 8 + 2 7 7 3 base 8 = Answer has to be in base 8

B). 1 3 5 D base 16 + 9 9 A base 16 = has to be in base 16

C). 1 1 1 0 base 2 + 1 1 0 base 2 + in base 2
```

Comment: Hello!!?? Try to do some homework and find out how to convert a string into a number.

Comment: Have a look at `int(num, base)`, `bin()`, `hex()`, and `oct()`.  Also read up on how to represent hex `0xNNNN`, bin `0b1011` and oct `0123`.

Answer (score 3):

So right now you're used to base 10. How does base ten work?

Well, you start counting in the one's position up to 9 and then when you want to add one more, it's not possible to represent ten with a single character so you have to reset your one position to the very bottom, zero and you increase the next position (the ten's position) by one. And when you get to ninety nine same deal you have to reset both the one's position and the ten's position to zero and you increase the hundred's position by one.

So in base 10, the most you can represent with 1 digit is 9 possible numbers
The most you can represent with 2 digits is 99 possible numbers
The most you can represent with 3 digits is 999 possible numbers

There's a pattern here I'll let you figure it out. And then you can apply the pattern to all the other bases and figure them all out.

And it's the same with base 8, you just have to get used to resetting and carrying earlier.

You count in base eight like this, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 but we don't have a single character that represents '8', it doesn't go up that high. Just like how in base 10 we don't have a singlecharacter that represents 10.

So here we have to carry it over to the next digit, the tens place. 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and again we have to carry it over and it becomes 20, 21 . . . etc.

And when we get to 77 we reset to 100 (which is 64 in base 10) and 777 to 1000 (which is?) in base 10?.

You can probably use like this to check your answers. http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/numbers/binary/bases.htm

It's OK if it takes you a while to get it. Learning a new language is quite literally about learning a new way to see the world. It's scary at first but pretty awesome later.

Good luck and welcome to programming!

Answer (score 1):

use `int(x, base=xxx)` to convert a string `x` representing an base `xxx` number to an integer, then sum the numbers up, and last use `bin`, `oct`, `hex` to convert the result to it's binary/octal/hex string representation.

Demo:

```
In [10]: lst = ['4', '3', '7', '1'] #assuming you have a list of strings

In [11]: oct(sum(int(i, base=8) for i in lst))
Out[11]: '017'
```